# python elasticsearch error in modifying and adding doc during remote access

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

Hello I have some questions..

I developed django website on Windows 10 and changed OS to ubuntu for publishing

On Windows, there were no problems but problems appeared on ubuntu

My website uses a remote access on EleasticSearch and also uses elasticsearch, elasticsearch_dsl python lib.

There was no error searching the document in index from an external connection, but an error occurs when adding update_by_query or a new document.

There are no other settings except for modifying network.host in elasticsearch.yml to 0.0.0.0

Do I need special permissions or other settings to modify or create documents from outside?

I am so stressed because of this.

If anyone knows, I'm sure you're busy, but please give me a detailed explanation or a link.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you send a request to the REST endpoints directly (I mean, without using the python client)? for example, by using curl

Comment: No,, I send a request by using the python client(elasitcsearch_dsl lib)

Comment: by "no" you mean that you don't have the same issue when sending direct requests? In that case, can you share your error message?

Comment: Sorry,, I misunderstood what you said. I don't have the same issue when sending direct requests by using curl. There seems to be an error only when using through Python.

Comment: Now when I use index refresh, the error occurs like:

elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fae1687a3c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fae1687a3c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)